# Why does my NWJS app open two icons in taskbar instead of showing shortcut icon open?

Tags: icons, taskbar, nwjs

Why does my NWJS app open two icons in taskbar instead of showing shortcut icon open? When i click on the shortcut icon it opens a whole new icon for app instead of showing the first one as open. It didn't do this at first. It just started suddenly doing it.

[image]

[image]